# Server doesn't receive body data sent through JMeter

Tags: jmeter, postman

In a POST API, this is in the body data

{
  "email_id": "wohit61@wmail.com",
  "password": "sampleTest"
}

But server isn't receiving anything. Same request is correctly processed on Postman and i'm receiving a 200 response code.

Please help! What is wrong am I doing?

Comment: show image of HTTP Request

Answer (score 0):

Blind shot: most probably you didn't add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), you need to add it to your [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) and configure it to send [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

[image]

---

Generic approach: if you can execute an API request successfully using Postman but cannot replicate it in JMeter the easiest way of getting things done is just recording your Postman request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Prepare JMeter for recording. The easiest way of doing this is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature.

   - From JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

     [image]
   - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start". You should end up with the following setup:

     [image]
2. Prepare Postman for recording.

   - From Postman main menu choose `File -> Settings -> Proxy`
   - Use `127.0.0.1` as proxy host
   - Use `8888` as proxy port
   - Tick both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` protocols

     [image]
3. Execute your request in Postman
4. JMeter will capture the request and store it under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you so much for your help. One more thing. I'm new to JMeter. Can you point me to a direction where i can learn to implement it in actual projects?